# connection to google cloudsql

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

im trying to connect to google cloudsql from appengine, but im facing this error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

my php file, that i have uploaded to appengine:

```
$sql = new mysqli(null,
'myuser', // username
'mypass'
'mydb',
null,
'/cloudsql/**:**'
);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
echo 'no';
die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
else {
echo 'yes\n';
}
```

the appengine is allowed from the cloud sql.
what should i do ?

Comment: What is the "real" socket that you are using, is the project name and instance name definately correct and in the format /cloudsql/project_id:cloud_sql_instance_name   ?

Comment: And you are getting this error when running it live on App Engine? As you cannot connect in this way from the development server (dev_appserver.py)

Comment: 1.- Is the code running on AppEngine (Google servers) or your local dev server? 2.- If it is running on App Engine, have you authorized the App Engine application to access your Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: - project name and instance are fine, i think. i took them from developer console -> my project name -> cloud sql -> column "instance id" (contain project name and instance name).
- yes, getting this error from running through AE.
- app engine, and yes i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to replicate the error you are getting but am unable to reproduce it when using code sample you provided.

Also your code sample has a few mistakes, you create your connection as **$sql** but then check **$mysqli** for connection errors, you should be checking $sql. So I have changed all occurances of **$mysqli** to **$sql** and you the more conventional way to check for a connection error is to check **connect_errno** and then read the message from **connect_error**

```
$sql = new mysqli(null,
    'your-username', // username
    'your_password_or_blank_if_using_root',
    'database_name',
    null,
    '/cloudsql/project_id:instance_name'
);

if ($sql->connect_errno) {
    echo 'no';
    die('Connect Error (' . $sql->connect_errno . ') '. $sql->connect_error);
} else {
    echo 'yes\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The socket file is actually /cloudsql/project_id:region:instance_id (i.e myproject-prod:us-central1:instance-1)
2. If you are on Flexible VM you might want to turn on debugging on one of your instances, then SSH to it, you can then verify the socket file indeed exists and try to connect over to it:

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install mysql-client
   mysql -u your-username -S /cloud/sql/your-socket-file -p